# Constant time multiplicative inverse within a word

Tags: block-cipher, modular-arithmetic

I was playing with an algorithm which at one step, calculated $f(x) = x^{-1} \mod p$ for $0 < x < p = 2^{64}-59$ (note $p$ is a prime). I used [Knuth's Vol 2 Algorithm X](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/euclidean.html#code-modinv) algorithm for calculating inverse modulo a prime, using the Extended GCD, but I was wondering if there was a way for making it run in constant time, within a word?

The [trick](http://www.joppebos.com/files/CTInversion.pdf) I found online for producing constant time inverses used Montgomery Multiplication, and therefore wouldn't fit within a 64-bit word.

My objective is to write a 64-bit [cipher](http://yberman.com/cipher59.c) which (is probably insecure, definitely slow, and) uses inversion for confusion and diffusion.

Edit: Specified $p = 2^{64}-59$, a prime.

Edit2: Specified the algorithm attributed to Knuth with link to page which has attribution.

Comment: Alternatively, would a blinded approach work (where the algorithm takes variable time, but time taken is uncorrelated to the value being inverted)?

Comment: For what value of $p$?  How large is your $p$?  If $p$ is small you can use a table lookup.

Comment: $p = 2^{64} - 59$ as in linked code.

Comment: @poncho, wrt a "blinded approach" the only think I could think of would to insert random multiples then strip them off? Calculate $(xr)^{-1}$ for random $r$, then multiply by $r$. I need to think about how to pull that off.

Answer (score 6):

You can compute $f(x) = x^{\phi(p)-1} \bmod p$ in constant time, using $O(\log p)$ constant time modular multiplies.  If $p$ is prime, this reduces to $f(x) = x^{p-2} \bmod p$

BTW: calling it 'Knuth's' algorithm is, in general, not very helpful; Knuth gives hundreds of different algorithms in 'The Art of Computer Programming'.  I assume you mean the Extended Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: That is correct. His Extended Euclidean algorithm. I am not sure how to take the an exponent if $2^{32} < p <2^{64}$, because products can overflow? That is why I didn't not use a Fermat's little theorem type based approach.

Comment: @Yosef: simple, use Knuth's algorithm! TAOCP Volume 2, 4.6.3, Algorithm A (it's over 3400 years old), reducing modulo $p$ at each step. Or any of the following ones.

Comment: @poncho: the algorithm I point to is the one to implement exponentiation (by right-to-left exponent scanning); so it is constant time (if modular multiplication and reduction is), and combined with your technique yields constant-time modular inverse. Designating this "Knuth's algorithm" was meant as an illustration of your note.

Comment: @fgrieu: oops, sorry about that.  In any case, his complaint was that it was inconvenient to do a modular multiply, given that his language doesn't have support for intermediate values > 64 bits

Answer (score 6):

This answers the [original question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/33252/2) in the particular case of $p=2^{64}$. It quickly computes the modular inverse of any odd 64-bit integer, hopefully on any compilers with 64-bit support conforming to C99 or later. It is constant-time if basic operations are (which is often a worry for multiplication).

```
#include <stdint.h>                     // for uint64_t and uint32_t

// given odd a, compute x such that a*x = 1 over 64 bits.
uint64_t invmod(uint64_t a) {
    uint32_t x = (((a+2u)&4u)<<1)+a;    // low  4 bits of inverse
    x =    (2u-1u*a*x)*x;               // low  8 bits of inverse
    x =    (2u-1u*a*x)*x;               // low 16 bits of inverse
    x =    (2u-1u*a*x)*x;               // low 32 bits of inverse
    return (2u-1u*a*x)*x;               //     64 bits of inverse
    }
```

Justification: $a\cdot x\equiv1\pmod{2^k}\implies a\cdot(2-a\cdot x)\cdot x\equiv1\pmod{2^{2\cdot k}}$

Note: the (revised) code uses `2u` and `1u*` so that all quantities involved have an unsigned type. In C, unsigned quantities yield a well-defined behavior: the results are reduced modulo $2^k$ for some $k$, such that the unsigned type represents integers $x$ with $0\le x<2^k$.

Comment: Thank you. I should have specified that $p = 2^{64} - 59$, the largest prime less than $2^{64}$. I failed to specify $p$ was prime. I thought it was implicit for the domain specification $0 < x < p$, but in retrospect, it is not. I also thought there would be a generic solution for all $p$, which makes the problem harder than a specific $p$. That being said, _this is really slick_.

Comment: This code has _undefined behavior_ on a platform that has a 64-bit `int` (most don't). Putting the letter `u` after each `0x2` solves this problem because the promotion to at least `unsigned int` will propagate to the multiplications, due to the left-to-right evaluation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795651/whats-the-best-c-way-to-multiply-unsigned-integers-modularly-safely

Comment: @Myria: the [code you commented](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/33261/3) works at least on a platform with 64-bit int using 2-complement that does not raise exception on integer underflow. But indeed the suffix `u`shall be used here. I originally posted `0x2`in hope that was more recognizable than than `2u` in my code, but I incorrectly remembered the rules governing signedness of hex constants without suffix (contrary to decimal ones, they _can_ be unsigned for some intervals of value, where I wrongly remembered they _allways_ are unsigned). Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I think `b*x` is still signed when `int` has 64 bits.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: That was a good catch! For `int` of 64 bits, and `b`and `x` of type `uint32_t`, indeed `b*x` is a (signed) int, potentially overflows, and is not formally specified, including in its low-order 32 bits. A generic solution to that issue of the C language is `1u*b*x`, which really forces the use of unsigned arithmetic. I now have simplified the code, and hopefully it is OK. The `1u*a` thing seems necessary for an hypothetical 80 or 128-bit `int` [re-posted with edit following revision of the answer].